# SQLite Updating first letter to be upper case

Tags: sqlite

I have a field, customer.country

Iam trying to update it so that the first letter of the values in country are upper case. I don't seem to be able to find out a way of doing that.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
UPDATE customer
  SET country = UPPER(SUBSTR(country, 1, 1)) || SUBSTR(country, 2)
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for non ASCII characters... (UTF-8)

Comment: @Sasho: you can compile [ICU extension](https://sqlite.org/src/artifact?ci=trunk&filename=ext/icu/README.txt) if you need support for UTF-8.

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you use [`substr()`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#substr) to get the first letter and [`upper()`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#upper) it?

```
upper(substr(customer.country, 1, 1))||substr(customer.country, 2)
```