# Make Each Word First Letter Uppercase Sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I want to be able to update each word in my string upper case.

**What i may have:**

```
the dog is brown
```

**What i want to have:**

```
The Dog Is Brown
```

Now i searched here before posting and came across this question: [SQLite Updating first letter to be upper case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16619917/sqlite-updating-first-letter-to-be-upper-case)

Using the provided accepted answers query: `UPPER(SUBSTR(field, 1, 1)) || SUBSTR(field, 2)` this updates the first word to upper case not all them?

Is there something that can be added to this to make it work for all words?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could perhaps use the following as the basis :-

### Testing table creation

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS sentences;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sentences (sentence TEXT);
```

### Load some Test Data

```
INSERT INTO sentences
VALUES 
    ('the dog is brown'),('pigs are pink'),('polar bears are white'),('orangutans are orange'),('zebras are black and white');
```

Table looks like :-

[image]

### The Query

```
SELECT 
    substr(
        replace(
            replace(
                replace(
                    replace(
                        replace(
                            replace(
                                replace(
                                    replace(
                                        replace(' '||sentence,' a',' A')
                                    ,' b',' B'),
                                ' c',' C'),
                            ' d',' D'),
                        ' e',' E'),
                    ' f',' F'),
                ' g',' G'),
            ' h',' H'),
            -- ..........
        ' t',' T')
        -- .............
    ,2) AS converted
FROM sentences
```

- This does words starting with a-h and also t
- It adds a space to allow conversion of the first word as per `' '||sentence` and then drops the space after all replaces have been done `substr(........,2)`.

### Result

[image]

Comment: Very complexed for something i thought could be small! Thanks though, will give it a shot and result back. Im guessing if i want a-z, i got to add all the rest in? xD

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    substr(
        replace(
            replace(
                replace(
                    replace(
                        replace(
                            replace(
                                replace(
                                    replace(
                                    replace(
                                    replace(
                                    replace(
                                    replace(
                                    replace(
                                    replace(
                                    replace(
                                    replace(
                                    replace(
                                    replace(
                                    replace(
                                    replace(
                                    replace(
                                    replace(
                                    replace(
                                    replace(
                                    replace(
                                        replace(' '||text,' a',' A')
                                    ,' b',' B'),
                                ' c',' C'),
                            ' d',' D'),
                        ' e',' E'),
                    ' f',' F'),
                ' g',' G'),
            ' h',' H'),
            ' i',' I'),
            ' j',' J'),
            ' k',' K'),
            ' l',' L'),
            ' m',' M'),
            ' n',' N'),
            ' o',' O'),
            ' p',' P'),
            ' q',' Q'),
            ' r',' R'),
            ' s',' S'),
            ' t',' T'),
            ' u',' U'),
            ' v',' V'),
            ' w',' W'),
            ' x',' X'),
            ' y',' Y'),
            ' z',' Z'),2) AS converted
FROM city_db.
```

Comment: Completed the above if anyone needs it

Comment: this is so inefficient. plus, there is function as UPPER for changing the case of a letter. you don't need to use `replace`

Comment: I don't like this solution, but there is no other options. @Siavash, if you have better solution - please provide

Answer (score 1):

```
str.split(' ').map((it, i) => {
  return (it[0].toUpperCase() + it.slice(1))
}
).join(' ')
```